# NSAttributedString/NSParagraphStyle: Xcode-like line break indentation

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsattributedstring

How to achieve an indentation for "line-broken lines" like in Xcode using NSAttributedString and/or NSParagraphStyle? Note that they get an additional indentation in Xcode.

[image: Xcode Screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `headIndent` property of `NSParagraphStyle` for this. You might need to calculate the appropriate amount of indentation yourself, based on the indentation width (tabs, spaces) of the (logical) line.

Comment: Thank you. I actually misread the documentation of the property.